# Ember.js Rails: Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I keep getting a "No model was found for '0'" error when trying to connect an Ember.js app to a Rails 3.2 API.  My setup is below.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Items Controller (Rails)

```
def index

  @items = Item.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @items, root: true }
  end

end
```

App.js (Ember.js)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('items', function() {
    this.route('backlog');
    this.route('board');
  });
});


App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('item');
  }
});
```

Server response when the Ember app makes request to /items

```
[
  {
    "item": {"id":1,"item_type":"Item","name":"Test item"}
  },
  { 
    "item": {"id":2,"item_type":"Item","name":"Test item 2"}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Ember-Data, your JSON format is incorrect. It's fairly poorly documented, so don't feel bad. The [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) has a brief example, but the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/) goes into more details. In your case, I think you want your response to look like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "id": 1, ... },
        { "id": 2, ... }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am using Ember-Data and have seen that this format is expected.  How do I configure Rails and/or my controller to respond with this format?

Comment: I got it working using the active_model_serializers gem.  After adding the gem and creating a serializer for my item model (with rails g serializer item) it responds with the json format you describe and it works!